# Restrict user management to user or role

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I just have a simple request, is it possible to restrict user management (add, remove, update, change password, etc...) to a single user or role within a tenant?  We create users and manage account passwords via the applications APIs using our mobile and server side applications.  The same account used by our applications used to manage the users within the tenant, via API, can manage everything within the tenant, via web console.  Which means if you know the userid and password, you have full admin access within the tenant.

I have assigned a test user to a role with anywhere from all permissions enabled to a minimal set to manage users through the web console with access to various components, but it completely breaks access to manage users via APIs.  Only if the test account is part of the built-in admin role does user management work through the API.

In all honesty, it doesn't sound very safe at all...and actually it seems very backwards.  Tenant level admin access should only be through the web console while access through the APIs should be minimal but include the ability to manage users, but without the need to be a tenant level admin.

If someone could point me in the right direction, I would be greatly appreciative.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to assign a specific set of permissions to the user accessing via APIs. These permissions will ensure that the User accessing via APIs does not have admin privileges.

What you can do is,

1. Create a new role. Let's call this as *Role A*.
2. Assign required permissions.
3. Assign *Role A* to the user accessing via APIs.

Refer to the [Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Configuring+Roles+and+Permissions) for more info.